# How can i scrape distinct data from a table in Java, Selenium and Chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So i want to **scrape** only a few details from a table with Selenium. I figured i out how to get to this page from a home page (as seen from my code).
I don't know how use the data-stat parameter in a table to print it out as it's not a TagName or anything like this. I can print out the whole table or just one data (with findElements) but my assignment is this:
With the parameter “Luka Doncic” and the current data (3PA), the program should display:
2020-21 8.2
2019-20 8.9
2018-19 7.1

This is the page:
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8C1W.png)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
public class Scraper {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   

        driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys("Luka Dončić");    
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[2]/div/button[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/input[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='players']/div[1]/div[1]/strong/a")).click();

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("div_per_game"));

        List<WebElement> elements = element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='per_game.2019']/td[12]"));

        List<WebElement> leto = element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        for (WebElement l : leto){
            System.out.println(l.getText());
        }

        for (WebElement e : elements){
            System.out.println(e.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Also if its for another player not Luka Dončić output should be the same only with more or fewer seasons and 3PA data (depends on a player)

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'to scrap' means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll write a function that takes the player's name as an argument, then searches for him and prints the data. I also found some selectors I like better than those long xpaths.

```
public void scrapePlayer(String name) throws IOException {
    driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('input[value="Search"]')).sendKeys(name);    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('input.ac-input')).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('strong > a')).click();

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("div_per_game"));

    WebElement[] seasons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('tr[id^=per_game'));

    WebElement[] threePointAttempts = []

    for(int j = 0; j < seasons.length; j++){
        threePointAttempts[j] = driver.findElements('td[data-stat="fg3a_per_g"]')[j];
        System.out.println(seasons[j].getAttribute('innerText') + " " + threePointAttempts[j].getAttribute('innerText'));
    }
}
```

I may have made a mistake or two, but I think this should give you the output you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tried your code but i do get two errors. One is on System.out.printIn(seasons[j]---> the error is: the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<WebElement> and the second is "the method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type List<WebElement>

Comment: Oh, I should have defined them as webelement arrays instead of lists. Just put `WebElement[]` instead of `List<WebElement>`, I'll update my answer

Comment: Interesting now when i put WebElement [] instead of List<WebElement> i get an error saying type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to WebElement[] (the error is at driver.findElement(By.cssSelector) and also at threePointAttempts[j] = driver.findElement... Any idea how should i fix this error? Sorry for my lack of skills it's my first even project in Java with selenium ..

Comment: It should be `driver.findElements()`, not `driver.findElement()`. updated my answer.

Comment: Its still a mismatch now cannot convert from List<WebElement> to WebElement[]..